# Does Twisted Fate's Ult grant vision during Nocturne's Ult?

Tags: league-of-legends

If Twisted Fate ults, and then an enemy Nocturne ults, will Twisted Fate's team have vision of their opponent's champs? If not, does that mean Nocturne's ultimate effectively counters Twisted Fate's ult if used after?

Answer (score 6):

Nocturne's ultimate takes priority.

Answer (score 1):

If Nocturne uses his ultimate AFTER Twisted Fate, the map would be blacked out, because Nocturne's ultimate takes priority as it was cast after TF's. Because of this, Nocturne's ultimate does counter Twisted Fate's.

Comment: How about the other way around? (i.e., can TF ult after Nocturne and see where Nocturne went/is going?)