# Does Nocturnes ultimate cancel out Twisted fates? And vice versa?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Twisted Fate's Ult grant vision during Nocturne's Ult?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58048/does-twisted-fates-ult-grant-vision-during-nocturnes-ult)

I was wondering if Nocturne used his ultimate while Twisted fates ulti was up(but he hadn't teleported yet) if he would lose vision? And the same with Nocturne.

Comment: [Try searching for it](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58048/does-twisted-fates-ult-grant-vision-during-nocturnes-ult)

Comment: i think i have seen it in rift myths

Comment: @Gigala The question Robin linked (and its top-voted answer) actually cites that episode of Rift Myths. :P

Comment: didnt see it was a link :)

Answer (score 2):

Hum I don't think so, When Nocturne uses his ulti, it only turn the whole map in fog of war, but TF can use his even if he has no vision.
On the other hand, when noc uses his ulti, you can't have any vision on the map, even on wards or marked units (with lee sin/kog/lulu/corki) so I don't think that you see ennemy champions with TF's ulti